# Fetching data from multiple APIs using Graphql / REST

Tags: api, rest, graphql

I have design question, on the approach that should fetch information about an entity from multiple applications and publish the result to the frontend at real-time. All of these applications can produce results abiding to a particular schema.

Currently I am using GraphQL, to combine the results from both the application source and concatinating the result to the frontend for users to compare and validate the data.

Ex: The query below, fetches the information of a client from two different applications through RESTful data source

```
const resolvers = {
    Query: {
      client: async (_source, { clientId }, { dataSources }) => {
        clientApp1 = await dataSources.App1ClientsAPI.getClient(clientId);
        clientApp2   = await dataSources.App2ClientsAPI.getClient(clientId);
        const client = [].concat(clientApp1, clientApp2); 
        return client;
      },
    },
};
```

**Schema**

```
  type Client {
    ssnNumber: String
    firstName: String
    lastName: String
    dateofBirth: String
    clientId: Float
    source: String
    contactList: [Contact]
    addressList: [Address]
  }
```

Currently this approach is working fine for top level entity like Client, but when we go to bottom of the chain, like contacts, address, transactions, the number of resultset returned expands drastically. With this approach I see 2 drawbacks, pretty sure, there could be more, but these are the once which are critical for me

1. Unable to add a filter in the backend Ex: return only App1 data
2. Unable to control number of records returned by each application at the lower level entities [pagination]

Question

1.Should I modify the approach to use Schema Stiching or GraphQL federation for better performance
2.Any better options outside of Graphql that I should look for, for combining the results from Multiple API's

Comment: GraphQL is a massive layer of complexity. What issue do you see with just calling 3 apis directly and writing a function that combines the result?

Comment: Number of applications involved may change and I am worried making 3 round trips may be expensive for the mobile clients. I want to keep the client very simplistic as possible, moving complexity of API accessibility  to the middle tiers.

Comment: usually joining different services and different resolvers/parts of req/res ... for the same part ... you can easily filter data by source ... you can paginate when you common index/sorting key used - fetch from both, limit/filter later, after concat, before return

Comment: Thanks xadm for your response, it make sense to paginate after collating the responses from the APIs, but I thinking if we could p propagate the pagination logic to underlying API's


Ex:
   await dataSources.App2ClientsAPI.getClient(clientId, first:2 after:"Y3Vyc29yMQ==");

Comment: hmmm, of course it/cursor won't work ... but read this/cursor record and use other ordering prop (id, createdAt) to fetch both APIs using universal filter (where id/createdAt), filter results, take the last record props to return new cursor?